# Android: Getting null value in islatedProcess

Tags: java, android, json, http, service

I have an App that run an isolated process.

The problem is, i'm getting correctly UserID from another Service but when I execute getUsersNotfs(url) I'm getting null on String s onPostExecute: 05-14 11:23:39.806 17705-17705/com.example.diabetes:offline_notifications I/System.out: null

But if I run this without an isolated process the String is correct and I get the correct results ([{"RecordID":"1","UserID":"1","RecordDate":"2018-05-08 00:00:00"}])

This is my code:

Passing UserID:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    uid = intent.getStringExtra("UserID");
    startTimer();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void getUserNotfs(final String urlWebService) {

    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            System.out.println(s);

        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                System.out.println(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String json;

                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }
                return sb.toString().trim();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }

    GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
    getJSON.execute();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Put a debug to see if Exception is catched

Comment: https://pastebin.com/n1DE6KQT @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolated process will have it's own instance hence you are not getting the value.

Try to use some persistent storage like SQLite,keep the value there and access from your isolated process.

You will get that.

As mentioned in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element#isolated

Your service is isolated from the rest of the system and has no permissions of its own. That means it dont have `INTERNET` permission.Hence can't fetch data.

Comment: But I need to check online database 1 in 1 second to get values.

Those values are returned in JSON Format.

Comment: Solved the problem.. Created a service but not isolated! 
Thanks